# How to implement @> (contains) clause for Postgres daterange type in Java Criteria API?

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, criteria-api

Is there any way to implement a where-clause with Postgres specific @> operator (witch means "contains") with Java Criteria API?

The original SQL is:

```
select * from rent_seasons rs where rs.period @> date '2019-07-16'
```

Table:

```
create table rent_seasons
(
    id         integer not null,
    name       varchar(191),
    period     daterange not null
);
```

What is the relevant Java Criteria API code?

Comment: try to implement the interfaces provided by the Criteria API (Predicate, Expression, etc..)